# The legend on user's tag badges page doesn't match the descriptions

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-badges, wording, badge-description

The descriptions state that you need 100/400/1000 *upvotes* in a tag, while the legend says you need 100/400/1000 *total score*. The tooltip on the tag badge itself needs fixing as well.

Comment: The tooltip on the tag badge itself needs fixing as well.

Answer (score 4):

I agree this needs to be fixed, it is supposed to be total score for the record, according to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100114/tag-badges-counters?rq=1).

> Downvotes do count against you in the counts, so the total in that block is upvotes in that category minus downvotes.