# Tag badges counters

Tags: support, tags, badges, tag-badges

I was reading about tag badges, but I don't understand how their counters works. In this image taken from my profile which is the actual counters?

[image]

- I think 9 for ruby is the counter for earning the tag badge, but then what is the `x 5` counter for the same tag?
- Downvotes count for earning the badge? If I have 103 upvotes and 4 downvotes for the same tag, will I earn the badge or I need to reach at least 100 in absolute value?
- If a question is retagged will I take tag points for the new tag or I take point only for current tags at vote time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You received a net 9 votes over 5 separate answers for Ruby.

Downvotes do count against you in the counts, so the total in that block is upvotes in that category minus downvotes.

You would get points for the new tag, but unless there's a good reason for doing so (the question is mislabeled, a more specific tag is available), it's probably better to leave as is.

Comment: P.S. Click on the box to see the 5 posts in question.

Comment: You've answered to all my questions, so I accepted your answer, but your answer raise another question: what if I had a downvote when I reached 100 upvotes? Will badge be revoked? Just for curiosity.

Comment: @Fabio - yes it will be revoked if you no longer meet the criteria - number of votes and number of non CW answers provided.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks, I wasn't sure with the tag badges.

Answer (score 1):

I realized, watching my profile, that the number at the right side (5) is the total amount (questions + answers).

However, the number on the left (9) is always the score of the answers.