# Inconsistencies on Tag Badge Counter on some Network Profiles

Tags: support, tags, badges, tag-badges

I have noticed some inconsistencies on the score I have on several tags in my account on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/). For example:

[image]

However, the *net vote count* (as DVs count [against you in the counts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100115/332286)) I have on those those tags are 106, 103, and 53, respectively. This I can see by clicking on those tags and manually adding the votes I have. For example, in the case of the `documentation` badge I have these votes (corresponding to the `2` answers I have on the tag):

[image]

The same inconsistencies I can see on the `intellectual-property` and `colleagues` tags (also on some others). However, I checked and this problem **does not happen on my  Stack Overflow profile**; there my tag scores have no inconsistencies. I have not checked on other sites I belong, as I am currently most active in TWP and SO.

Is there something I ignore that would justify that "inconsistence"? Or could it be some bug?

*Note*: The last time I answered questions with those tags was last week, giving it plenty of time for the servers to update their counters (therefore waiting for the counter to appear correct may not work). Also, do tell if I need to add some other info to clear this out.

Comment: Its maybe not related, but I found that if I add tag to the question after I do answer, the tag does not update correctly in the windows you displayed, as I witnessed the same error as you reported

Comment: Good observation. Seeing the [Edit History](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/98147/revisions) of the question I have 103 votes on I can see that the `documentation` tag was there from the beginning (that is the OP included it from the beginning). However, the `intellectual-property` tag was added some time after to that question. But still, the documentation one should not have problems given that what you are saying were completely true

Answer (score 0):

Seems that no there are *no more inconsistencies*:

[image]

now they match the number of votes I have on those tags, like in `documentation`:

[image]

This period of inconsistence was because I received an upvote I didn't notice **just before** I happened to see the inconsistence (I rep capped that day, so no +10 notification was made and didn't check the reputation drop-down details). Now that some time has passed, and no new upvotes have been done on those tags the counter has updated correctly.