# Add status-completed tag to my question

Tags: support, tags, self-answer

I asked a question yesterday here on Meta SE regarding a possible bug (support), and today I found that the problem was gone. I also found *why* that possible bug was gone, so I [answered my own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300652/332286) to indicate so.

Therefore my question is now solved (still have to wait a day to accept it, and possibly more, in case a more detailed explanation is posted). However, when I tried to edit my question to add the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag, it indicated that it was only for "moderator use".

**Is there a process or way for me to add or suggest that tag to my question now that is solved?** Also, **Should users be allowed to add [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) to their *own* questions?**

*Note*: I read [How can a user suggest a status tag edit on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193545/how-can-a-user-suggest-a-status-tag-edit-on-meta), but in this case I am not suggesting an edit, as it is my own question.

Comment: That's not really "completed" (no manual action was taken to correct things), it's "norepro". There's a close reason for that, which is simpler to apply.

Comment: @NathanTuggy According to the tag excerpt "This tag indicates that the site developers were unable to recreate the behavior described in a bug report." Does not really sound like it applies, as that now-discarded bug can be reproduced, besides that tag should be after they actually try something right?

Comment: status-completed is not for "my question is resolved" - it is only meant for cases where a moderator or staff member actually took action to resolve something (usually by implementing a change). A situation where you just missed something doesn't warrant the tag.

Comment: @animuson thanks for your explanation, now I understand better. Also could the Downvoters explain their reasons?

Comment: @GrayCygnus: "Tag scores are cached" is consistent; "my tag scores are out of date" will drift in and out of reproducibility from time to time, which isn't useful; "my tag scores are out of date, and not just because of caching" (the implied problem) was never reproduced at all, and can't be.

Comment: That was not a bug, just some temporary glitch somewhere server side which fixed itself. No need in any status tag on those.

Comment: I see @ShaWizDowArd your comment is really helpful to understand why not put status tag on it

Comment: How is that "status completed"? Sounds like "status-norepro" or "status-bydesign".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a process or way for me to add or suggest that tag to my question now that is solved?

You can flag your question as "in need of moderator intervention" and suggest the addition of the appropriate moderator tag in the flag explanation.

> Should users be allowed to add [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) to their own questions?

No, this would allow users to falsely mark a feature request they suggested as completed when it really isn't. Since only moderators can add the tag users can be sure that the request really has been completed.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, will flag accordingly from now on

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @animuson:

> status-completed is not for "my question is resolved" - it is only
>   meant for cases where a moderator or staff member actually took action
>   to resolve something (usually by implementing a change). A situation
>   where you just missed something doesn't warrant the tag.

Consequently, I would not advise flagging to ask for it to be added because I would expect that flag to be rejected.