# Allow high-reputation users or topic experts to "endorse" answers posted by other users

Tags: feature-request, answers, voting, accepted-answer

### The problem

I am a Physics Stack user and I made a [feature request](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14594/proposing-answer-endorsement-badge) that I was told would be a better fit for the mother meta site. I am a user who primarily answers way more than I ask.

In short, the Physics Stack seems to have a lot of questions that are deemed worthwhile enough to keep (after  going through thorough question moderation) and so, they get answered. But then the answers get no votes one way or another. I am talking about maybe 1 or 2 votes (total votes, not net score).

A lot of the time, even simple conceptual questions take a lot of time and effort to answer (because the concepts are just hard) and having been through the learning process I know that a lot of the questions I am answering are worthwhile.

I see lots and lots of posts with excellent quality answers that are sitting at 0, 1 and 2 votes, no accepted answer mark and that's it. On the other hand I see many terrible answers that are sitting at similar amounts. **What I am saying is that *it feels like* the community doesn't really moderate answer content in Physics Stack.**

On the same token we have many active users with expert knowledge and high amounts of reputation on specific tags. Their opinion carries a lot of weight.

### The solution

So, I was wondering if the following feature could be implemented.

[image: screenshot of endorsement under answer]

A **high tag rep user endorses this answer** note, like Piazza has for instructor and TA. This could have a queue like the first question queue. High rep users on some tag could browse questions that (since they passed Question moderation, which is rigorous in Physics Stack) are useful, and have been answered, but with unmoderated answers. This could simply also be a note that a high rep user on that tag upvoted the answer.

I know that they can already do that with their 40 votes per day and a little comment saying “this makes sense to me” but this endorsement, next to where the accepted answer checkmark is, would be a bigger differentiator which I feel like Physics Stack needs. Also comments are meant to be temporary.

[This is similar in some ways to what Codidact implemented already.](https://meta.codidact.com/posts/284455)

It also could come with some associated rep which maybe would entice people to answer questions more and just use the site more in general.
Also, this might help with the common side problem of users answering in the comments, making their answer unjudgeable by the community via votes (a common problem in Physics Stack).

I don't use any other Stack but I would imagine other Stacks with expert users and low vote volumes could also use this.

Could this feature be implemented please?

### Addressing questions/suggestions raised in comments

Question: How is this different to the bounty system?

Bounty system entices users to answer questions. The difference here is that I am talking about the large volume of excellent answers that already exist but, to the non-expert users, they are of unknown quality since they are sitting at low vote count. My suggestion is more about answer moderation than rep. **All I want is for in/correct answers to be perceived as in/correct, which they don't due to low vote volume and low "accepted answer" mark usage.**

Question: Why not propose a competition or rep-sharing thing on your local meta?

**The sheer volume and constancy of these type of answers requires a permanent solution.** Do mind , my solution is more about answer moderation than rep rewarding.

> Comment by High rep Physics user PM2 Ring:  The underlying problem is that people don't vote enough. It can be
> hard work to properly evaluate an answer on science sites, even if you
> are an expert in the topic,... I vote fairly frequently (in both directions), but I don't
> like to vote unless I'm fairly confident that the answer is actually
> correct (or incorrect)

This comment is true and it endorsements are in line with this because in Physics (and science more generally), an expert’s confidence means a lot.

Comment: There already exists an anonymous content rating system that has proven effective since the beginning of the site.

The voting system that works for some sites doesn’t work for others for the reason PM2 Ring outlines. “We’ve always done it like this” is a bad justification for many so things… In science, one reliable, confident voice carries a lot of weight. Endorsements would be in line with this.

Question/suggestion: Asking hi-rep users alone to endorse a post with their voting does not solve the problem of a community refusing to endorse a post with their voting. Get everybody to do it using the system that already exists. This is unnecessary extra pressure on a small fraction of the community.

“Get everybody to do it with the system…” I can’t force people to vote but I can give users the **choice** to use a new tool to moderate answers. If a system already exists and its not being used, one ought to find alternatives. Remember, this site is fully voluntary, there is no “pressure”.

I will continue answering good faith questions in the comments as they come. I consider this sitting at an almost neutral score (when we are approaching 30 votes) quite encouraging.

Comment: There's already the option to place a bounty on good answers that deserve more attention. How would this be different?

Comment: You can reward an existing answer though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: @JohnA. - Why not propose a competition or rep-sharing thing on your local meta? "*Let's reward the ten best unsung questions*" kinda thing...

Comment: Answered above.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is a penalty for downvoting an answer (a loss of reputation: -1).  This discourages downvoting on answers, which means that bad answers don't always get the downvotes they deserve.

Comment: While this has never bothered me, I see this as a reason in favour of more answer moderation efforts. Thanks for the thought!

Comment: The underlying problem is that people don't vote enough. It can be hard work to properly evaluate an answer on science sites, even if you are an expert in the topic, especially if the answer doesn't include relevant references, equations, etc. On SO, you can run the code in an answer to see if it works, but we don't really have an equivalent on Physics.SE. I vote fairly frequently (in both directions), but I don't like to vote unless I'm fairly confident that the answer is actually correct (or incorrect).

Comment: But when someone IS confident, in physics, it means a lot. Hence endorsement. I will add this to the post

Comment: Suppose someone accepts the task. If, in the future, that person wishes to abandon the site and unlink their name from the platform, would the endorsement given by the user also disappear, or would their endorsement history be automatically transferred to the *Anonymous User*?

Comment: Endorsements can be anonymous and a privilege gained by reaching a high tag reputation. The note can include the user reputation (rounded). They can also be revoked like accepted answer makr. Thus, I see no need to delete it. Any that were given non-anonymously, could become anonymous after the user leaves the site. If a higher rep user on that tag feels the need to re-endorse an answer that was endorsed by someone with less rep, they can both be there or maybe the higher rep one can stay.

Comment: So, is the intention of the proposal to have the site simply feature two content rating systems? There already exists an anonymous content rating system that has proven effective since the beginning of the site. Adding a new system seems more like a platform for user self-promotion, diverting focus from the content. If there's a shortage of users on the site or a lack of voting on answers, there should first be a debate on the specific Meta Site about the culture and common goals of the community.

Comment: Answered above.

Comment: Asking hi-rep users alone to endorse a post with their voting does not solve the problem of a community refusing to endorse a post with their voting. Get everybody to do it using the system that already exists. This is a waste of developer time and unnecessary extra pressure on a small fraction of the community.

Comment: I'd edit your screenshot to highlight or red-freehand-circle the green text to make it clearer what you're referring to. The first thing I saw there was "where students collectively construct a single answer", which I consider a major fault of how Piazza is designed.

Comment: What do you mean by "seems to have a lot of questions that are deemed worthwhile enough to keep"? Is this statement based on the number of votes a question has gathered, or on the number of views the question has had, or on the length of time the question has "survived", or on the fact that the question has been answered once (or more)?

Comment: Answered comments s above

Comment: Can you please clarify the intended effect of this change? Is this supposed to give answer authors more immediate rep, like a "super upvote"? Is this supposed to feature answers, like a public reading list? Is this supposed to just show agreement, similar to the acceptance checkmark? Mind, you might have already said so but it is difficult for me to figure out.

Comment: To sum it up, you raise a very good point. The reputation system is not fair, flat and simple. But there's no simple way to fix it, your suggestion might help a bit, but super complex to implement, and overall just not realistic in the current state of Stack Exchange. Bottom line, those who answer should be doing it for other reasons than just gain reputation. So the high rep users can upvote, and leave comments like "Thanks for this answer, highly appreciated", and delete the comments after a while so it won't become just noise.

Comment: @MisterMiyagu, fair. The post has accumulated a mass of text now. Main point is to modify answer moderation via adding expert users endorsement to address the large volume of good questions with good answers but no indication of whether the answer is good, due to a lack of voting

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda are you with the dev team? If so, thanks for reading my post. I’d like to clarify that its more about moderation than rep. It’s an interesting insight to know this would be hard to implement

Comment: @JohnA. I'm not in the dev team but well aware of the mechanics and what's realistic and what's not. Also related: [Is there skill endorsement in Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182900/is-there-skill-endorsement-in-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: As a side note, please don't feel bad due to the negative score here, it's really not personal and doesn't mean your request isn't valid (in such case it would have been closed and it's not), just that people don't agree with what you suggest. Cheers and thanks.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda The stack where I come from a -4 is fine (ironically related to post). I am glad this is getting discussion. Also 5 people agreeing is great!

Comment: Sounds somewhat similar to this failed experiment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction

Comment: It's not at all supposed to be similar to that. Let me know so I can edit post for clarity

Comment: Maybe related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project

Comment: How does this differ from a bounty?

Comment: Answered in post

Comment: If people can't be bothered to vote on a post, why would they be bothered to endorse one?

Comment: Same reason some users are mods or high answer # users. They like to contribute. 1 endorse is supposed to be enough of a differentiator, 1 vote is not

Comment: This seems to be incomprehensible: *"A x > (some rep) user endorses this answer note, like Piazza has for instructor and TA."*. Perhaps rephrase?

Comment: Great suggestion. Makes more sense in Phys S.E

Comment: @JohnA. No, it isn’t. Bounties can already address this, why introduce another thing?

Comment: @user3840170 What about the answer to your question on the post is unsatisfactory?

Comment: What if on Stack Overflow 500 people endorse a post. Do we have to scroll through all of those endorsements?

Comment: No, this needs to be done in a reasonable manner when implementation comes. Im acting in good faith and don’t want to break the site. Also if it up to me, this would only be implemented in smaller S.E’s

Comment: That there is none. You can already endorse answers by setting up a bounty (even a low amount like +50 will do), picking “reward existing answer”, and awarding it after some time passes. Why is that not sufficient?

Comment: It is different because this is about moderating a large volume of answers by expert users. Not about rep recognition or enticing answers. bounties have nothing to do with moderation

Comment: It sounds quite similar to "reactions" which was [implemented at Codidact](https://meta.codidact.com/posts/284455). Is that what you are proposing here as well? Notably Codidact does not have an "accepted answer" feature though, so they do things a bit differently.

Comment: I wasnt aware of this, but in some ways it it similar @Lundin. How did it work out for them?

Comment: @JohnA. It isn't used as much as we thought initially. I've used it there for self-answered Q&A where I wished to make my own answer "the official one". It is possible to customize these by community though. For example the Code Golf challenges site has a reaction "invalid" for incorrect solutions. I think Codidact is probably much more flexible than SE when it comes to implementing specific features for a certain site.

Comment: It’s great to hear additional features that would come in implementation. It would probably be used a decent amount in Physics S.E.

Comment: This would be a great use of the "roles" system that was supposed to be being worked on, before all this AI shtuff put everything else on hold.

Comment: SE was designed to move away from judging quality by taking into account a particular person’s credentials. I sympathize with your frustration; quality measurements by uncorrelated raters requires a lot more samples per question than any of the smaller sites can muster. I think going back to credentialism is a step backwards though. Maybe curation events where the community picks a topic and focuses on just those questions and answers. Relying on a few experts to carry an entire community seems like a recipe for failure. It would be better to find some way to get more people engaged.

Comment: Is rep what you mean by credentials @ColleenV

Comment: No. Reputation doesn’t correspond with expertise on SE. It correlates with activity and familiarity with the system mostly. When you designate someone as worthy of endorsing a post, and their assessment trumps voting by the community, you’ve given them credentials. Whether you do that by selecting them using a poor measure of expertise, like reputation, is irrelevant to my point.

Comment: Poeple getting 10k rep on the quantum field theory tag are definitely experts by the way they answer questions. I agree about this for simpler topics like homework tag

Comment: Someone with 10k in a particular tag over the course of a decade is not more of an expert than a modern Feynman who joined the site today and has 1 reputation. SE is designed to try to overcome knowing who the author is to be able to judge whether their answer is correct.

Comment: Could make it recent rep, the implementation specifics are not super important in the comments now. I agree about the 10 years though

Comment: I see no reason to believe "It would probably be used a decent amount in Physics S.E." - you may like to think that, sure.

Comment: @ jonCuster this might be so. Not I 100% admit I am speculating here. This is not for my personal gain, it however will dictate how much I feel like I want to use the site. Not sure why users think I am acting in bad  faith

Comment: @JohnA. - I did not mean to imply that you are acting in bad faith. I will note that you have been on Physics for 4 years, and in that time cast 337 total votes there. Would an endorsement system have been used more by you? Why or why not? The issue is more voting, not trying to bolt another system on.

Comment: Ive been on the site for 2 weeks, used up all my votes everyday. Look rep graph. 20-12-23 is when I started. (account is old because 1 Question 2019, then nothing  for 4 years). I 100% agree i wish voting worked. Couldn’t contribute before because I didn’t really know any physics before, i used as a search engine only. I actually started using it because Qmechanic answered a question very usefully. Is 300 votes in 2 weeks a lot?

Comment: @JohnA. - good to see I'm wrong and you are leaping in to active participation. One thing to note is that, as you gain more rep, there are more avenues for input - the various review queues. I've picked a couple to be active in, and focus my attention there. If a question should be closed, I vote to close instead of downvoting it. One side effect of this is I have more votes on answers than questions. I also find that life gets in the way of continuous high involvement (your mileage may vary).

Answer (score 3):

In an ideal world, readers would be able to tell which answers are correct regardless of whether they have been upvoted because every answer would be objective and its assertions would be supported by credible sources. Voting increases visibility so that the best answers according to the community are the ones that are presented to readers first. Votes are somewhat correlated with correctness, [but not always](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12089/80039).

Quality answers not getting more upvotes than mediocre answers is a problem across the network, but I don't think it can be resolved by giving individual users the responsibility to pick up the slack. Why should someone who discovers an answer on the network through an internet search give any weight to an endorsement of quality from J. Doe, random person they've never heard of or interacted with?

I think setting up members of a community with "super-votes", regardless of how they are selected, would make things worse, not better. In my opinion, solutions to this issue should try to get more people engaged with content moderation and curation. A robust solution would account for community turnover and engage more than just the veteran active users.

I think the first step is always to collect information and validate assumptions, but here are some random thoughts about the issue because JohnA asked :)

- Should we incentivize searching for answers with the express intent of voting on them? Maybe the problem is simply a visibility issue and people with enough reputation are too focused on too few questions and answers.
- Should we normalize score by age and views maybe instead of calculating it directly from votes? (but not change the reputation calculations)
- Should the Community bot's "bump" function be tweaked to give potentially under-voted answers more visibility?
- Should sites have more support for community events that could be used to tackle curation issues, sort of like volunteers getting together for a day and cleaning trash from an area?
- Should we give users statistics on how their votes and flags correlate with the community in general, so that they can tell if their judgment of quality aligns with the community?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree that *any* solution that increases votes overall would be great too! I'd love it if you expanded your thoughts on specific solutions to increase vote counts. Ultimately I want to solve the answer moderation problem more than I want my specific solution to be implemented. +1 for this answer. I personally don't see   how to get sporadic users or non-expert users to vote for correctness.

Comment: @JohnA. To be honest, I don't have any solutions that are thought through well enough to share. There are a lot of levers to pull. Visibility of answers, incentivizing quality over popularity, giving feedback to voters on how well their curation aligns with the community to try to get more correlation, more tools for people to engage with each other instead of focusing on just engaging with content... I have lots of thoughts but also not a lot of spare time:)

Comment: Might want to add these thoughts to your post given that comments become noise after a long time. (E.g. the 40+comment thread in this post that no one will read )