# I need a pair of binoculars to see the badge award count

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, badges, design

...from space, since [it's huge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/36/stellar-question) on the trilogy sites:

[image: huge badge award count]

I know it's meant to be emphasized, but given that it dwarfs any of the other text on the site and it doesn't seem to be consistent with the [styling used](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/181/altruist) on other non-trilogy sites in the network, I feel like this probably isn't desirable.

Comment: +1 for humor.  In a few days we will make some tweaks, and I agree that looks a bit big.

Comment: Excellent! There's [another issue on those pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68002/the-legend-on-users-tag-badges-page-doesnt-match-the-descriptions) that could benefit from a minor tweak as well, in case it wasn't on your radar.

Comment: Agreed. Every time I see the giant number it seems to be saying, "SO HOW COME YOU DON'T HAVE IT?"

Comment: 45px. 45 pixels. That's huge indeed, not to mention not consistent with the font size of other elements which is relative i.e. given in percents. On other sites it's 120% size which is sane.

Comment: @Jeremy no announcement on the fix? :)

Comment: I almost expected to see "binoculars provided" as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to have been fixed:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPFLn.png]

Comment: You need a pair of binoculars to see the question tagged [status-completed] 7 hours before you answered it.

Comment: Yea... This is not an answer.

Comment: @Lix I added screen shot of the fixed page

Comment: @Antony exactly. I knew this would be met with downvote[s], but I did it anyways.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I think you did the right thing. Grokking through the meaning oh-so-freking-prominent [meta-tag:status-completed] seems easy only to meta regulars; vast majority of SE readers would probably initially perceive the question as they do at non-meta sites: un-answered, ignored and abandoned. If we want meta to be convenient to read for major SE audience, we better strive for conventional "indicators" like answered, accepted

Comment: Especially since Community♦ is going to bump the question otherwise... like now.

Comment: @JanDvorak let's bump it again: bump ;)